# Spring Security Token Authentication How to Authenticate?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, restful-authentication

I am building a RESTful API based on Spring, Jersey, Spring Security, and Tomcat. I found this tutorial that seems great but it never discusses how to actually authenticate users, which seems like a major piece ([Stateless Authentication with Spring Security and JWT](http://technicalrex.com/2015/02/20/stateless-authentication-with-spring-security-and-jwt/))

Anyway I based my implementation from this and now I'm struggling to figure out how to authenticate and get the token back.

I've provided what I thought was all the relative code below. Now the question is how do I actually authenticate and get a token back?

I gave it try with this but I'm not getting Token back in the response headers.

```
@Component
@Path("/auth")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class AuthenticationEndPoint {

    private UserSecurityService userService;

    @Inject
    public AuthenticationEndPoint(UserSecurityService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @POST
    public void doSomething(CredentialsDTO credentials) {
        SecurityUser user = userService.loadUserByUsername(credentials.getUserName());
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(),credentials.getPassword(),user.getAuthorities());
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
    }
}
```

Here is my Spring Security configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(2)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private StatelessAuthenticationFilter statelessAuthenticationFilter;

    @Inject
    private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;

    @Inject
    public SecurityConfig() {
        super(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .exceptionHandling().and()
                .anonymous().and()
                .servletApi().and()
                .headers().cacheControl().and()
                .authorizeRequests()

                // allow anonymous resource requests
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()

                // allow login
                .antMatchers("/api/auth").permitAll()

                // all other requests require authentication
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()

                // token based authentication
                .addFilterBefore(statelessAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Custom User:

```
public class SecurityUser extends User {

    private org.company.app.domain.User user;

    public SecurityUser(org.company.app.domain.User user,
                        Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities) {
        super(user.getEmail(),user.getPasswordEncoded(),grantedAuthorities);
        this.user = user;
    }

    public org.company.app.domain.User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(org.company.app.domain.User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
        return this.user.getRoles();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("user", user)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

Filter:

```
@Service
public class StatelessAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private final TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    @Inject
    public StatelessAuthenticationFilter(TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService) {
        this.tokenAuthenticationService = tokenAuthenticationService;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
                         FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Authentication authentication = tokenAuthenticationService.getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
    }
}
```

TokenAuthenticationService

```
@Service
public class TokenAuthenticationService {

    private static final String AUTH_HEADER_NAME = "X-AUTH-TOKEN";

    private final TokenHandler tokenHandler;

    @Inject
    public TokenAuthenticationService(TokenHandler tokenHandler) {
        this.tokenHandler = tokenHandler;
    }

    public String addAuthentication(HttpServletResponse response, UserAuthentication authentication) {
        final SecurityUser user = (SecurityUser) authentication.getDetails();
        String token = tokenHandler.createTokenForUser(user);
        response.addHeader(AUTH_HEADER_NAME, token);
        return token;
    }

    public Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        final String token = request.getHeader(AUTH_HEADER_NAME);
        if (token != null) {
            final SecurityUser user = tokenHandler.parseUserFromToken(token);
            if (user != null) {
                return new UserAuthentication(user);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

TokenHandler:

```
@Service
public class TokenHandler {

    private Environment environment;
    private final UserSecurityService userService;
    private final String secret;

    @Inject
    public TokenHandler(Environment environment, UserSecurityService userService) {
        this.environment = environment;
        this.secret = this.environment.getRequiredProperty("application.security.secret");
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public SecurityUser parseUserFromToken(String token) {
        String username = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(secret)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody()
                .getSubject();
        return userService.loadUserByUsername(username);
    }

    public String createTokenForUser(SecurityUser user) {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(user.getUsername())
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret)
                .compact();
    }
}
```

Implementation of Spring Security Authentication interface

```
public class UserAuthentication implements Authentication {

    private final SecurityUser user;
    private boolean authenticated = true;

    public UserAuthentication(SecurityUser user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return user.getAuthorities();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getDetails() {
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        return authenticated;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAuthenticated(boolean b) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        this.authenticated = b;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }
}
```

Finally my implementation of UserDetailsService interface

```
@Service
public class UserSecurityService implements UserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserSecurityService.class);

    private UserService userService;

    @Inject
    public UserSecurityService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    private final AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker detailsChecker = new AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker();

    @Override
    public SecurityUser loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        logger.debug("Attempting authentication with identifier {}", s);

        User user = userService.getUserByUserName(s);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User with identifier %s was not found",s));
        }

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getSpringName()));
        }

        return new SecurityUser(user,authorities);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you solved this problem??

Answer (score 0):

We do in our project something similar. We send the JWT token as a part of response body.
The Client which is written in AngularJS takes the token and stores in the browsers memory.
Then for all subsequent secured calls the client embeds the token in the request header as a Bearer token.
Our JSON for authentication looks like this :

```
{
    "username": "auser",
    "password": "password",
    "dbname": "data01"  
}
```

and for every usiquent request we add the below in the request header

```
Bearer <token>
```